# Toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi-teensy error. Platformio project for teensy 4.1

Tags: platformio, teensy, gnu-toolchain

I have a project where I want to use a teensy 4.1. I'm programming through platformio and am running into a major issue right now.

My first task is to read a text file and append each column to a different vectors. Each vector represents a stepper motor and its position each keyframe. Ideally, I want to read this text file and use the position data to calculate feedrate and general stepper motor control. I plan on controlling 8-16 stepper motors using tmc trinamic drivers. I wish I could use python but given the amount of stepper motors I want to drive, there isn't much documentation out there supporting that. But back to the issue.

I found a snippet of code that uses the vector, ifstream and iosstream libraries to read a txt at a specific filepath and run through it. Here's that code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

// put function definitions here:
void kuperImport(){
    std::vector<double> vecX, vecY;
    double x, y;

    std::ifstream inputFile("C:\\Program Files\\Modo16.1v7\\kuperSH1.txt");

    while (inputFile >> x >> y)
    {
        vecX.push_back(x);
        vecY.push_back(y);
    }

    for(double i(0); i < vecX.size(); i++)
        std::cout << vecX[i] << ", " << vecY[i] << std::endl;
  }

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  kuperImport();
}
```

However, this is the error I am running into. Any thoughts on how to solve this? I've tried to do a bit of digging myself and came up short with little answers:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3b8c.png[error][1]
```

I tried installing the toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi and ARM software to no avail. Tried adding them to my PATH and nothing helped.